# Folding & Heating function not working on wing mirror

Tags: electrical, vw, golf

Car is a VW Golf GTI Mk5 (2006).

The folding and heating function on passenger mirror isn't working. Everything else works, including electronic mirror adjustment and puddle light.  Heating/folding works for driver side.

I've taken the wing mirror off and can't find any open circuits on the wiring loom. It doesn't look like these things are individually fused and replacing the mirror glass didn't resolve heat issue.

Where should I be looking next?

Very appreciative of any help.

Comment: Does the  passenger mirror have a 0.5mm brown ground connection? or voltage on a 0.5 green/white to a 5amp fuse/F25 onto F31 5amp to a wire 0.75 green/yellow.back to the mirror control switch.??

Comment: The mirror doesn't, but it's connected to a door control unit which does.  The layout is:  Battery -> F29/50A (Fusebox A) -> F32/30A (Passenger Compartment Fusebox) -> Passenger Door Control Unit -> Mirror.  There's CAN Convenience lines into the passeger door control unit which I assume is how it gets its instructions.

Comment: Could it be an open gnd? DMM results may help isolate fault

Comment: Just started pouring with rain here but I'll get back out there and check the ground when it stops.

Comment: Just had a test now.... Drivers side is 022.7 M Ohms and passenger (not working) is 024.3 Ohms (no M). This is testing continuity with the wing mirrors and glass attached to the car, ignition off + keys out, connecting to the terminal elements behind the glass.

Comment: Also need voltage when activated

Comment: Just got the voltages:

Drivers Side (working): 13.3V, stable and consistent.

Passenger: 3.3V but unstable and inconsistent, dropping to millivolts.

I'll be honest - I don't know what to deduce from this. Very much appreciating any help provided :)

Comment: Voltage to passenger side is open except for some capacitance somewhere feeding back from the source.  Trace the problem backwards until you get 13 V and verify 0 Ohm  ground connection 1st , chassis to door electronics